# error in build angular app for prod

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I'm trying to build my angular app using this :

```
ng build --aot
```

but i get this :

```
ERROR in ./src/main.ts Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in...
```

angular 4.4.6 / angular-cli 1.5.5

Answer (score -2):

please try this command
ng build --aot=false that will ignore that error

Comment: That does not provide a solution to the problem, it just avoids it.